# wireless security concern

Tags: network, access-control, wireless

My small office has Netgear Router (N300 DGN2200). I had it secured using "password" . So any computer which needed access had to give the security password. But today a outsider accessed my router for using internet without the password. He even showed me my password required to access network. He used proxifier , freeportscan etc.  My question is how he did it and how can i protect my network from such access in future.

Comment: What wireless protocol are you using? If it's WEP, it's trivial to break into. You should make sure to use WPA2 with a strong password.

Comment: it shows WPA2-PSK [AES] in security options. the hacker showed me my passphrase !?

Comment: Was the password just "password"? If so, he just did a dictionary attack.

Comment: Welcome to Security.SE. As it stands, this question does not have enough information. Can you update the question with information as per @Poly's comment. Also, why don't you ask the 'outsider' to tell you how he did it? If he said he used proxifier etc., then that may well be his access technique. Of course, he could have just guessed 'password'... Anyway, please update the question, or it is likely to be closed as not a real question (see the [faq] )

Comment: no its very difficult actually. Its 12 character strong including special characters.

Comment: he tried to show me but "failed". He said he did port scanning. then used proxifier. But when i asked to do it in front of me he could not. I want to protect my network first and then understand what he did. thanks.

Comment: If you have a decently strong password and use WPA2-PSK, I find it difficult to believe that he is able to crack your password.

Comment: in my router admin ...there are 2 checkboxes:            
Enable SSID Broadcast (enabled)
Enable Wireless Isolation(not enabled)  does these can help in making things more hardcore.

Comment: the guy has applied for a job at my place ..and he is still in my office for few days as temp...i will still ask him to do the steps in front of me again.But i guess as a fresher/trainee can do it ..its something old trick which everyone knows in security domain.

Comment: If he can't demonstrate it to you, call his bluff and tell him that's his barrier to employment - demonstrate it or you don't get the job. Do you really want to hire someone who is _already_ trying to deceive you?

Comment: he fumbled while demonstrating ..he just used the two tools ..i have to recreate same steps on another laptop later to check his process. But fact remains he accessed my network and showed me my passphrase. I have to secure it ASAP.

Comment: my internet bandwidth limit depletes very fast and maybe my neighbors are having fun at my cost!

Comment: Why is a prospective employee trying to crack your network?

Comment: Its definitely illegal and stupid coz if any virus infects from his laptop our work will get affected. i have stopped him but it does exposed a vulnerability ..and my most neigbors are techies and i feel insecure now.

Comment: This makes no sense. First, you try to employ him. Then he hacks into your wifi, and won't show you how you did it. Not only is that grounds for _not_ hiring him, it's grounds for arrest. But instead of going to the police, you try to hire him still? I really cannot understand the situation. It's certainly not a good fit for StackExchange, since you've provided very little detail and don't seem to know what's happening yourself.

Comment: see..i have been asking you for help as it happened ..i have now made up my mind to kick out the guy ...but the main question which remains unsolved ...and do tell me what details do you need ...i will provide screenshots or a short video as well if needed. thanks for your valuable time and effort.

Comment: So change the passphrase, its obvious, your passphrase wasn't complicated enough.

Comment: my pass phrase is 9 character long with special characters. Its unique and difficult for dictionary attack or social engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use WPS to setup your router?  If so, it could have been cracked using [reaver](https://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/).

There was also recently a more complicated attack which uses [dns rebinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) to [hack millions of routers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r13ESXEfQVE).

If not, it is possible that you used an easily crackable password (Dictionary word, short character length, non-complex, etc.)

From there, in order to get onto your router itself he would also need the login credentials.  Did you change these to be different than the defaults?

The other vectors of attack are either social engineering, getting the password from someone who knows it, or attacking your PC/laptop itself and dumping the hashes/configuration information.

Was the password used to secure your wireless network/router the same password that you use on other accounts?  If so, perhaps another account was hacked and they just correctly assumed you used the same password again.

Comment: WPS seems likely. I'd guess from there he pulled the router config out of UPnP - a lot of manufacturers are stupid enough to include the WiFi password in the XML response.

Comment: yes its WPA2-PSK [AES]. My passphrase is very long and unique with special characters. He challenged me to change passphrase and he will be able to connect again. My router credentials are default !!!? its *****/********...but isnot one required to connected with wire to access 192.168.1.1 ?

Comment: You should change your router credentials.  I bet you that he has compromised a device on your network and is tunneling through your router from the Internet.  Watch the below youtube link starting at 29:30 because that may be in play as well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r13ESXEfQVE

Answer (score 0):

You can either use stronger security protocol , choose a "hard to guess " password and  change it frequently ,  or if you have MAC filter in your router and your network is not very dynamic , you can build a table based on the user's MACs and the router will not accept any connection form outside the table.(of course  you can new users to the table when you have new employees )

Comment: MAC addresses can be spoofed in a few seconds, MAC filters don't really do anything.

Comment: @InvertedLlama They do help prevent drive-by attacks that go for low hanging fruit, though.

Answer (score 0):

If he can't reproduce the steps required to "hack into" your wifi, maybe it's a simple as one of the other employees telling him the password. If he had access to one of the company pcs/laptops he could have also used software like [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) to get the password from there.

Since your router apparently supports WPS, it the "hacker" might have also used the [reaver tool](http://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/wiki/README) to gain access to the network.

Comment: hmm..no one knows password except me. he did access a computer but for a very brief time ..all he might have looked is network name. still i will check for any installed software.

Comment: You can extract the wireless key very quickly from the registry directly.  It wouldn't require any special software.  The software just makes it easier.  (Though you do have to know how to decode it.)

Comment: how can i know if he checked registry or installed and then uninstalled any software on office pc